# unexpected else in ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In one of my views i have this code:

```
<% if params[:icd_id] == '' %>
<% @icd2.each do |f| %>
<% else %>
<% @icd1.each do |f| %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "#{f.von} - #{f.bis}  #{f.bezeichnung}", diagnose_index_path(:pa_id => @patient, :icd1_id => f.id)%><br>
<% end %>
```

But something im making wrong! I get the error:

```
index.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else
```

What did i wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You opened a block with `do` and then the next line is `else`. You just can't do that.

I'm think you're trying to do this

```
<% if params[:icd_id] = '' %>
  <% @icd2.each do |f| %>
    <%= link_to "#{f.von} - #{f.bis}  #{f.bezeichnung}", diagnose_index_path(:pa_id => @patient, :icd1_id => f.id)%><br>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <% @icd1.each do |f| %>
    <%= link_to "#{f.von} - #{f.bis}  #{f.bezeichnung}", diagnose_index_path(:pa_id => @patient, :icd1_id => f.id)%><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

but I'm assuming you want it more concise. You can do something like this

```
<% (params[:icd_id] == '' ? @icd2 : @icd1).each do |f| %>
  <%= link_to "#{f.von} - #{f.bis}  #{f.bezeichnung}", diagnose_index_path(:pa_id => @patient, :icd1_id => f.id)%><br>
<% end %>
```

Also note to use `==` instead of `=` to check for equality. `params[:icd_id] = ''` will otherwise always be `true`

Comment: Besides that probably typo in first line `=` instead of `==`

Comment: Is there nothing shorter?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the double loop, you might use a ternary operator to determine which variable to iterate over.

```
<% (params[:icd_id] == '' ? @icd2 : @icd1).each do |f| %>
  <%= link_to "#{f.von} - #{f.bis}  #{f.bezeichnung}", diagnose_index_path(:pa_id => @patient, :icd1_id => f.id)%><br>
<% end %>
```